# Moving List View items from one list to another

Tags: c#, winforms

I'm writing a form that contains 2 ListViews with a set of 4 buttons. 2 move all the items from one to the other in each direction, the other move only selected items in each direction.

Nothing fancy or complicated.

However I'm feeling like I could write the MoveItem method in a more elegant way and was wondering if any would mind taking a look and advising me.

```
private void MoveItem(ListView source, ListView dest, bool all)
{
    if (all)
    {            
        foreach (ListViewItem item in source.Items)
        {
            source.Items.Remove(item);
            dest.Items.Add(item);
        }
    }
    else
    {
        foreach (ListViewItem item in source.SelectedItems)
        {
            source.Items.Remove(item);
            dest.Items.Add(item);
        }
    }
}
```

Any suggestions would be thankfully recived

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Before thinking about how to write this in a more elegant way, you should first ask yourself: is this code actually correct? The “problem” with that code is that you're iterating the collection you're modifying. Quite often (for example in the case of `List<T>`), that's not allowed and your `foreach` would throw an exception. Fortunately for you, the enumerator of `ListViewItemCollection` iterates over a *snapshot* of the collection of the items, so your code will actually work fine (although I didn't find this behavior documented anywhere).

Now, if you want to refactor code like this, just have a look at what's the same and what's different. You can notice that the only different thing in the two branches is the source of the `foreach`. So, just create a local variable for it, set it correctly and then have common code that iterates it:

```
private static void MoveItem(ListView source, ListView dest, bool all)
{
    var items = all ? source.Items : source.SelectedItems;

    foreach (ListViewItem item in items)
    {
        source.Items.Remove(item);
        dest.Items.Add(item);
    }
}
```

Comment: So would I be correct in thinking that with a normal list that doesn't create a snapshot the best solution would be to create my own copy of the items and then add/remove them? That refactoing was just what I was trying to do and failing as `SelectedItems` and `Items` are different types that don't inherit from a common base class but do implement `IList`

Comment: Yeah, exactly. And the easiest way to create that snapshot is using `ToArray()`.

Comment: Does this work? Modifying a list while looping over it don't cause an exception?

Comment: @mmdemirbas, like I said, in this specific case it *does* work, because `ListViewItemCollection` creates a snapshot before you start iterating and then you iterate over that snapshot. Because of that, it's safe and it does work.

Comment: If you need to iterate and change, you can either repeatedly use-and-remove the first item until the list is empty, or do a `for(int i=list.Count-1; i>=0; i--) { ... }`.

Comment: I would say that even though it does work and is safe, the code looks like it is modifying an existing collection and is thus better written with an explicit snapshot.

Comment: @BillBarry, I agree. When I first looked at the code, I thought it's incorrect and it surprised me it actually work. Surprising code is not good.

Comment: How does this work? My code won't compile because it doesn't know what `items` should be. `Type of conditional expression cannot be determined because there is no implicit conversion between 'ListView.ListViewItemCollection' and 'ListView.SelectedListViewItemCollection'` .NET 4.0

Answer (score 1):

Easier:

item.Remove <-- will remove item from the ListView it is currently assigned
DestinationList.Items.Add(item);